# Kafka error running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java-native-interface, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os) tutorial to configure and run Apache Kafka on Windows 7. I have managed to run it at some point and everything went fine. I used to run zookeeper before running Kafka using the command `zkserver`. However, at some point, after I tried to re-run it again I got the following error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I'm using this command to run Kafka on the command prompt:

```
Path\to\Kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I'm using this version of Kafka: kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0, and this version of Zookeeper: zookeeper-3.4.9

Any ideas on what's wrong with this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of JDK you are using to run Kafka ?

Comment: Hi @Kedar. I'm using jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: Kafka itself comes bundled with ZooKeeper version which is pre-configured to be used to Kafka. Can you confirm that everything works with bundled ZooKeeper ?

Comment: Hi @Kedar. Thanks for replying!
The problem was just fixed after I have restarted my computer. Now I'm able to run Zookeeper using the command `zkserver`  and run Kafka on windows using the command `path\to\kafka>bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties`